# Is it possible to draw vertical border only for left column of a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is it possible to draw vertical border only for the left column of a DataGridView?

For instance:

[image]

---

**Note:** I know how to work with [DataGridView](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial).

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add handler for `CellPainting` event and change cell border styles there:

```
private void HandleCellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex > 0)
  {
     e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Right = 
     e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
  }
}
```